# Random crash at the end of successful UI Test with Embassy

Tags: swift, mocking, uitest

We use Embassy to mock web requests for UI Tests in Swift.

It crashes randomly at the end of a successful test.

Crash: Thread 28: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3100000000)

The initialization of Embassy is done like shown in project or tutorials.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still the same solution like in the issue here: https://github.com/envoy/Embassy/issues/31